# Basic Scatterplot in d3.Js (issue with Scales)

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot

First off all I am very new to d3.js. So any solution please explain in very simple terms :)

I am trying to replicate this scatter plot using d3.js from https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexisbcook/scatter-plots/tutorial

**I am only see two dots. My hunch is there is an issue with my yScale and xScale.**

[image]

Here is my html and js code:

```js
async function drawScatter() {
  //STEP 1- Access Data
  //******************
  // data from: https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexisbcook/scatter-plots/tutorial
  const dataset = await d3.csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AhmadMobin/bmivscharges/main/Example1_BobRoss/insurance.csv"
  ) //("./insurance.csv")
  //console.log(dataset)
  //console.table(dataset[0])

  const xAccessor = (d) => d.bmi
  // console.log(xAccessor(dataset[0]))

  const yAccessor = (d) => d.charges
  // console.log(yAccessor(dataset[0]))

  //STEP 2- Chart Dimensions
  //************************

  //*Note: Scatter plots is typically a square
  //*will take the smaller value of either the window width vs window height
  const width = d3.min([window.innerWidth * 0.9, window.innerHeight * 0.9])

  //set the dimensions and the margins
  let dimensions = {
    width: width,
    height: width,
    margin: {
      top: 10,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 50,
    },
  }
  //use the dimensions and margins to calculate the width and height of the bounds (the chart area)
  dimensions.boundedWidth =
    dimensions.width - dimensions.margin.right - dimensions.margin.left
  dimensions.boundedHeight =
    dimensions.height - dimensions.margin.top - dimensions.margin.bottom
  console.log(dimensions) // check to see if dimensions.boundedWidth = dimensions.boundedHeight

  //STEP 3- Draw Canvas
  //*******************
  //adding the wrapper and bounds to the html element

  //wrapper (total visual area)
  const wrapper = d3
    .select("#wrapper")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", dimensions.width)
    .attr("height", dimensions.height)

  //bounds: area available for the chart
  const bounds = wrapper
    .append("g")
    .style(
      "transform",
      `translate(${dimensions.margin.left}px, ${dimensions.margin.top},px)`
    )

  //STEP 4: Create Scales
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  const xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor))
    .range([0, dimensions.boundedWidth])
    .nice()

  //    console.log(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor)) // min = 15.96 ; max = 53.13
  //     console.log(xScale(53.13))

  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor))
    .range([dimensions.boundedHeight, 0]) // min = 10043.249 ; max = 9991.03765;
    .nice()
  //console.log(d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor))
  // console.log(yScale(9991.03765))

  //STEP 5: Draw Data
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  const dots = bounds.selectAll("circle").data(dataset)
  console.log(dots)
  dots
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
    .attr("cy", (d) => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "#af9358")
}
drawScatter()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>


    <title>Scatterplot:Example1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to my github repo: https://github.com/AhmadMobin/bmivscharges/tree/b7441c3ac30713419e0c5614377367bec7d2c93c/Example1_BobRoss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line #58, you have a comma before "px".

Additionally, you are missing parseFloat() in the xAccessor and yAccessor. Remember that you still need to parse numeric values after you have downloaded data from CSVs in D3.

My js file has been updated as well (see here: https://github.com/AhmadMobin/bmivscharges/tree/main/Example1_BobRoss)